# Reading from an Excel file

Tags: c++, excel, csv, fstream

I am trying to read from an Excel file that has four columns and 121 rows. I tried the .csv idea, but I guess I understood it wrong because when I compile this, it gets all messed up.

How can I make sure city gets the first cell, country gets second, lon gets third, and lat gets fourth?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream inFile;

string city;
string country;
string lat;
string lon; 
inFile.open("worldcities.csv");
if (inFile.is_open()) {
    cout << "File has been opened" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "NO FILE HAS BEEN OPENED" << endl;
}


while (!inFile.eof()) {
    inFile >> city;
    inFile >> country;
    inFile >> lon;
    inFile >> lat;
    cout << "City: " << city << endl;
    cout << "Country: " << country << endl;
    cout << "Lat: " << lat << endl;
    cout << "Lon: " << lon << endl;
}
inFile.close();
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by it gets all mess-up

Comment: Look at my answer and do let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Lamour It was putting the whole first row for city and one random cell for country and messing the rest up. I got help but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
while (!inFile.eof()) {
    getline ( inFile, city, ',' );
    getline ( inFile, country, ',' );
    getline ( inFile, lat, ',' );
    inFile >> lon;
    cout << "City: " << city << endl;
    cout << "Country: " << country << endl;
    cout << "Lat: " << lat << endl;
    cout << "Lon: " << lon << endl;
}
```

Comment: @PaliiBenet glad that it helps.